# How to fill empty elements in a json

Tags: r

I have a strange json files from which some row-elements are missing total. I try to fill them with NA or null but I can't aim it.

Here is an example of the situation
Example of json:

```
require(RJSONIO)    

json_file <-  '[{"name":"Doe, John","group":"Red","age (y)":24,"height (cm)":182,"wieght (kg)":74.8},
    {"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Green","age (y)":30,"height (cm)":170,"wieght (kg)":70.1,"score":500},
    {"name":"Smith, Joan","age (y)":41,"height (cm)":169,"wieght (kg)":60,"score":null},
    {"name":"Brown, Sam","group":"Green","age (y)":22,"height (cm)":183,"wieght (kg)":75,"score":865},
    {"name":"Jones, Larry","group":"Green","age (y)":31,"height (cm)":178,"wieght (kg)":83.9,"score":221},
    {"name":"Murray, Seth","group":"Red","age (y)":35,"height (cm)":172,"wieght (kg)":76.2},
    {"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Yellow","age (y)":22,"height (cm)":164,"wieght (kg)":68,"score":902}]'


json_file <- fromJSON(json_file)
```

From the first row it is missing the score label from the 3rd row it is missing the group label and from 6th row it is missing the score.

Json with more levels:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Lora",
      "surname": "Ann",
      "time": 30,
      "light": {
        "full": 4,
      },
      "height": {
        "id": 156,
        "weight": {
          "pounds": 88,
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ann",
      "surname": "Lora",
      "light": {
        "full": 2,
      },
      "height": {
        "id": 173,
        "weight": {
          "pounds": 55,
          "kilo": 56,
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsonlite will make this into a dataframe and automatically fill in NAs for missing values for you.

```
require(jsonlite)
json_file <- fromJSON(json_file)

          name  group age (y) height (cm) wieght (kg) score
1    Doe, John    Red      24         182        74.8    NA
2    Doe, Jane  Green      30         170        70.1   500
3  Smith, Joan   <NA>      41         169        60.0    NA
4   Brown, Sam  Green      22         183        75.0   865
5 Jones, Larry  Green      31         178        83.9   221
6 Murray, Seth    Red      35         172        76.2    NA
7    Doe, Jane Yellow      22         164        68.0   902


> fromJSON(json_file2, flatten = TRUE)
  id name surname time light.full height.id height.weight.pounds height.weight.kilo
1  1 Lora     Ann   30          4       156                   88                 NA
2  2  Ann    Lora   NA          2       173                   55                 56
> fromJSON(json_file2, flatten = FALSE)
  id name surname time full height.id height.weight.pounds height.weight.kilo
1  1 Lora     Ann   30    4       156                   88                 NA
2  2  Ann    Lora   NA    2       173                   55                 56
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do you know if it works for  not only the first level of json? I have updated the question with an example of data.

Comment: The JSON example you provided is invalid ;)
But if we fix them we see that it does work with multiple levels.

Comment: thanks again for your quick replay. Please could you tell what is wrong with the json I provide because I am new and I would like to start learning?

Comment: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Put your JSON in here and see what errors occur.
In this case, 
"full":4,
is expected to have } instead of a comma, because there are no proceeding values.